# Store multiple values at the same memory address. Delimiter?

Tags: memory, masm, mov, readprocessmemory

I'm doing some tinkering with Read- and WriteProcessMemory and an old platformer game I found laying around. Whenever the player enters a new level, enemies are created and the health points, coordinates etc for each one is set:

```
0056BE76 - c7 80 38 01 00 00 64 00 00 00 - mov [eax+00000138],00000064
```

(EAX being the address of the struct and 138 the offset to their health)

Granted there is free memory to write, is there any way I could store the value of EAX of each one in one and the same location? Like using a delimiter of sorts?

Cheers

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here.  There are many enemies, each one is loaded into a memory location, at the point in the code you've shown, they're health is set.  And you're looking to store the addresses (EAX register contents) at some other location in memory?  For each enemy?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, i think you can use an union

http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=c209/union.c

Comment: I don't see how using a C language construct (a union) is going to solve an assembly problem.